# IndexError obstructing code from working with larger csv file

Tags: python, csv, indexing, pandas

I have data that sorts a csv by using groupby and then plots the information. I used a small sample of information to create the code. It ran smoothly and so then I tried running it with the huge file of data.

I am pretty new at Python and this problem has been quite frustrating so even suggestions on how to troubleshoot this problem would be helpful.

My code is stopping in this section:

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.DataFrame.from_csv('MYDATA.csv')
mode = lambda ts: ts.value_counts(sort=True).index[0]
```

I tried selecting only parts of the huge data file and it ran, but for the entire thing I am getting this error:

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

But I've looked at the two data set side-by-side and the columns are the same! I noticed that the big file has some utf8 issues with accents and I am working on combing those out, but this IndexError is perplexing me.

Here is the traceback

```
runfile('C:/Users/jbyrusb/Documents/Python Scripts/Tests/tests/TopSixCustomersExecute.py', wdir='C:/Users/jbyrusb/Documents/Python Scripts/Tests/tests')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-45-53a2a006076e>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/jbyrusb/Documents/Python Scripts/Tests/tests/TopSixCustomersExecute.py', wdir='C:/Users/jbyrusb/Documents/Python Scripts/Tests/tests')

  File "C:\Users\jbyrusb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 682, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\jbyrusb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/jbyrusb/Documents/Python Scripts/Tests/tests/TopSixCustomersExecute.py", line 23, in <module>
    df = df.groupby('CompanyName')[['Column1','Name', 'Birthday', 'Country', 'County']].agg(mode).T.reindex(columns=cols)

  File "C:\Users\jbyrusb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 676, in agg
    return self.aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\jbyrusb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2674, in aggregate
    result = self._aggregate_generic(arg, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\jbyrusb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2722, in _aggregate_generic
    return self._aggregate_item_by_item(func, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\jbyrusb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2751, in _aggregate_item_by_item
    colg.aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs), data)

  File "C:\Users\jbyrusb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2307, in aggregate
    result = self._aggregate_named(func_or_funcs, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\jbyrusb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2394, in _aggregate_named
    output = func(group, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:/Users/jbyrusb/Documents/Python Scripts/Tests/tests/TopSixCustomersExecute.py", line 20, in <lambda>
    mode = lambda ts: ts.value_counts(sort=True).index[0]

  File "C:\Users\jbyrusb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 915, in __getitem__
    return getitem(key)

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Comment: You should try to provide data so that others can reproduce your results.  My guess is that your groupby is returning an empty data frame, hence why it can't be indexed.

Comment: @Alexander Unfortunately the data is confidential and also probably way too long. I'm interested in your guess though, that would definitely make sense for the error. I just don't understand what's different about the new csv file.

Comment: ts series maybe empty: `ts = pd.Series([]); 
ts.value_counts(sort=True).index[0]` will raise the same exception.

Comment: @HYRY the error with ts = pd.Series([]) is SyntaxError: can't assign to lambda, not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult without seeing the data causing the error, but try this:

```
mode = (lambda ts: ts.value_counts(sort=True).index[0] 
                   if len(ts.value_counts(sort=True)) else None)
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the try even though I don't have data to give you. This didn't work but I still appreciate it!

Comment: @jenryb Please try the amended version above.

Comment: The way it's formatted in your amended version is yielding an unexpected indent error. I've tried moving it around but can't get it to work.

Comment: YOU DID IT! Thank you so much. If possible, can you explain what this is doing, so I know what to do if I run into this in the future?

Comment: The `[0]` indexes the first item of `ts.value_counts(...)`.  If nothing is returned by this function, you will get an index error.  To avoid this, you only perform the indexing when the length > 0 (`if len(ts.value_counts(sort=True)` will evaluate to True if it is not None and the length is greater than zero).  Otherwise, assign a None value (`else None`).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue i resolved by changing the sep argument from 
sep='\t'
 to 
    sep=','.

Hope it saves someone.